# Why isn't my variable set when I call the other function?

Tags: python

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

I have looked for an answer in Stack Overflow and found that I should be taking an int(input(prompt)), but that's what I *am* doing

```
def main():      
    while True:
            vPopSize = validinput("Population Size: ")
            if vPopSize < 4:
                print("Value too small, should be > 3")
                continue
            else:
                break

def validinput(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            vPopSize = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Entry - try again")
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Comment: You will need to add `return vPopSize` in the `def validinput(prompt):`

Comment: The problem isn't the input. Python will implicitly `return None` from the valid input function. And there are two different `vPopSize` variables here

Comment: I would make `validinput` boolean

Answer (score 47):

This problem also comes up [when migrating to Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons).

In Python 2 comparing an integer to `None` will "work," such that `None` is considered less than any integer, even negative ones:

```
>>> None > 1
False
>>> None < 1
True
```

In Python 3 such comparisons raise a `TypeError`:

```
>>> None > 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

>>> None < 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to add a return in your function to get the number you input, otherwise it return an implicit None

```
def validinput(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt)) 
            # there is no need to use another variable here, just return the conversion, 
            # if it fail it will try again because it is inside this infinite loop
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Entry - try again")


def main():      
    while True:
        vPopSize = validinput("Population Size: ")
        if vPopSize < 4:
            print("Value too small, should be > 3")
            continue
        else:
            break
```

or as noted in the comments, make validinput also check if it is an appropriate value

```
def validinput(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(prompt)) 
            if value > 3:
                return value
            else:
                print("Value too small, should be > 3")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Entry - try again")


def main():      
    vPopSize = validinput("Population Size: ")
    # do stuff with vPopSize
```

Comment: Thanks very much all!! I guess I lulled myself into thinking the return was implicit!! Daft really, but there you go... thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Changing None value worked for me [np.nan documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/misc.html)

```
df_gpa.replace(to_replace=[None], value=np.nan, inplace=True)
```

code before

```
    def validate(self):
        df = self.df['column_name']
        print(df)
        for i in df:
            if i < 0:
                raise Exception(f"range is lower than 0.0: {i}")
            if i > 150:
                raise Exception(f"range is higher than 150: {i}")
```

code after

```
    def validate(self):
        df = self.df['column_name']
        df.replace(to_replace=[None], value=np.nan, inplace=True)
        print(df)
        for i in df:
            if i < 0:
                raise Exception(f"range is lower than 0.0: {i}")
            if i > 150:
                raise Exception(f"range is higher than 150: {i}")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Try: 
    def validinput(prompt):
    print(prompt) # this one is new!!
    while True:
        try:
            vPopSize = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Entry - try again")
            continue
        else:
            break
```

And you will notice when the function is called.

The problem is that validinput() does not return anything. You'd have to return vPopSize

Answer (score -5):

should remove print() from the return of the function, so take the value and print it from outside